# Are the trends leaning towards developing in the cloud or local?

Tags: localhost, cloud, development-environment, trend, trending

***Would you say that the trend of developers is to leverage cloud development environments rather than local desktop environments?***

Learning about Cloud 9 and other similar cloud dev platforms, it seems that there are some major benefits over local development.

Team collaborative efficiency, speed to deployment, and streamlined workflows to name a few.  I have little experience in the cloud dev realm and would love to hear from someone with their pulse on this trend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professional work over the last decade has been exclusively more "cloud" development in the sense that we use VMs on a beefy server for development work. I tried cloud 9 and it's not quite the same experience, but it's getting there.

Reasons are what you expect, such as streamlined workflow. Less time setting up dev systems for new employees when we can just stand up a VM. Firewall rules on remote systems are all easier to manage, etc.